# How to get Google oauth 2 access token and refresh token using c# without using Google Library

Tags: c#

Can anyone help me to get Google access token and refresh token without using Google dotnet library. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you tried _anything_ so far? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Checkout this post about oauth2: http://www.geeklife.ch/dev/soundcloud-client-c/

It's with soundcloud, but should work also with google!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I test the code on the geeklife.ch/dev/soundcloud-client-c and my code returns this error : "The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed."

Comment: That will be comprehensive, why would you like to do so? Please take a look at the API documentation: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2 to get a bit more understanding. Then you might want to choose some of the great .NET wrappers available.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, now I am able to use OAuth2 with Google Libraries for .Net.